# Spring declarative transactions and manually scheduling threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I'm having a strange issue.

In a class I have:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executor 
     = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public MyClass(final MyService service) {
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            service.foo();
        }
     }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

`MyService` is a spring bean that has `@Transactional` on its `foo` method. `MyClass` is instantiated only once (effectively singleton in the application)

After the first invocation of `service.foo()` (which works fine), on subsequent requests to the application I am randomly getting:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[]])] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@2cd91000] bound to thread [http-bio-8080-exec-10]

A few observations:

- when the exception is thrown, the session stored in the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` is closed
- the transaction synchronization manager resource map for the manually scheduled thread is empty
- the exception occurs in `http-bio-8080-exec` threads, but the manually scheduled one is a `pool-` thread - so there is no 'thread polution'
- `MyClass` is instantiated on startup, in a thread named "Thread-5", i.e. it is not in any way related to the `http-bio` threads.

If I comment the invocation to `service.foo()`, or get rid of the `@Transactioanl` annotation, everything works (except, of course, that data is not inserted in the db)

Any clues what the issue might be?

(Note: I prefer not to use `@Scheduled` - I don't want `MyClass` to be a spring bean, and the runnable has to operate on some of its internal state before invoking the service)

**Update:** After a while I'm able to reproduce it even without the scheduling stuff. So probably a general spring problem with the latest snapshot I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that exception comes from an invocation of the [TransactionInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html) or the like (some Spring infrastructure bean), or are you using the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` from your own code somewhere? It appears to me that something is binding sessions to a thread being managed by your container (is that Tomcat 7?) and failing to unbind them before they're returned to the container's thread pool. Thus when the same thread is used for another transactional request later, Spring can't bind the new Session to it because the old one wasn't cleaned up.

I don't actually see anything to make me think it's directly related to your custom scheduling with `MyClass`. Are you sure it's not just a coincidence that you didn't see the exception when you remove the `service.foo()` call?

If you could catch one of those threads in a debugger when it's being returned to the pool with a Session still bound to it, you might be able to backtrack to what it was used for. An omniscient debugger would theoretically be perfect for this, though I've never used one myself: [ODB](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/) and [TOD](http://pleiad.cl/tod/) are the two I know of.

**Edit:** An easier way to find the offending threads: add a Filter (servlet filter, that is) to your app that runs "around" everything else. After chain.doFilter(), as the last act of handling a request before it leaves your application, check the value of [TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html#getResourceMap%28%29). It should be an empty map when you're done handling a request. When you find one that isn't, that's where you need to backtrack from to see what happened.

Comment: thanks. Yes, it's the transaction interceptor that triggers all that. I tried putting breakpoint on "bind" and "unbind", but you can't easily track things that way.

Comment: oddly, now it appears even without the scheduled stuff. Perhaps there's something wrong with the spring snapshot I'm using. I'll switch to RC1 and see

Comment: I didn't observer the exception without service.foo because I didn't wait for it long enough to pollute the threads. I switched to RC1, but the issue remained. Then I commented all my recent changes. The issue persisted. Reverted to M2 - works fine. It seems to be an issue with RC1, which is rather bad. Reporting to spring & accepting your answer

Comment: Wow. Yeah, that's a little bad. I'm kinda glad you found that and I didn't :)